# Node http request to Docker Remote API - No response

Tags: ajax, node.js, docker

My NodeJS application talks to Docker Remote API and manages Docker containers. I use AJAX to talk to my nodejs application.

### Problem:

The 6th Request never receives response from Docker Remote API. Only the first 5 requests receive response.

### Sample application:

https://gist.github.com/boopathi/8156caa3bbd09d17685f#file-infinite-js

`node infinite.js` stops after 5 times, and waits forever.

Happens only with Node. Tried using curl and golang, and it doesn't happen.

parsed mtrace output for infinite.js:
https://gist.github.com/boopathi/8156caa3bbd09d17685f#file-infinite-mtrace

Comment: I am having this exact same problem. It seems to me that the Docker Remote API just simply does not respond in certain situations. I've been using dockerode to communicate with the Remote API. First I ran into a problem when trying to tag the resulting image after a build. Fixed that by using the tag option in the build request instead. Now I am trying to perform a sequential break down and rebuild and start. Meaning remove image, than rebuild, than start. I can do them fine on their own but I try to do any of them back to back it ignores the second request. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the max sockets to some higher value.

```
http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 100;
```

Or you could disable socket pooling by passing agent parameter in request.

```
var req = http.request({
    agent: false,
    ...
}, successCallback);
```

Ref 1: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets

Ref 2: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent